# Constrained interpolation to fill gaps in a time series with R

Tags: r, constraints, interpolation, spline

I have a time series with some missning values (NA's) which I want to interpolate in a nonlinear way. I know that the missing values are in a given interval, but this is block-specific. My data looks like that:

[image]

I know that I can do spline interpolation, which works really nice. However, how can I introduce the constraints? For example, in the first block of missing values, I know that the missing values should be in the interval [-1, 1], and in the second block of missing values, the missing values should be in the interval [-.45, -.5]. So the constraints are subject to the block of NA's.

Any recommendations for packages or help is highly appreciated!

I tried spline interpolation, and used splines with constraints. However, I was not able to find out how to adjust the constraints for each block of NA's.

Comment: Please read the info at the top  of the [tag:r] tag home page annd in particular please provide the input as text using `dput` as others do not want to have to retype it to work with it.  Also please clarify where the constraints come from.  Are these  somehow derived from the data shown and if so how or are they additional inputs.